# Проблема при удалении item из RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

При удалении последнего item'а из RecyclerView, выкидывает ошибку

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 //инедкс и размер одинаковый
```

При удалении других item'ов всё работает, только последний ругается.

```
fun removeItem(contex:Context, position:Int, viewHolder:RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {

    dbHandler = DBHelper(contex, null)
    removedItem = items[position]
    removedPosition = position

    dbHandler.deleteNote(removedItem.id)
    items.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)

    Snackbar.make(viewHolder.itemView, "${removedItem.name} removed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("UNDO") {
        items.add(removedPosition, removedItem)
        dbHandler.addNote(removedItem)
        notifyItemInserted(removedPosition)
    }.show()
}
```

Comment: по хорошему лучше бы воспользоваться room и viewmodel: вы подписываетесь на изменение данных в базе, и при любых изменениях у вас всегда актуальные данные https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html

Answer (score 0):

ошибка `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` говорит о том, что в коллекции 0 элементов, а вы пытаетесь удалить элемент по индексу 0, но его нет, т.к. коллекция пустая.

Comment: При удалении последнее элемента, например из 5 элементов, выдаст ошибку java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5. Не могу понять в чём дело. Список заполняется из базы данных.

Comment: индекс 5 обращается к 6му элементу, т.к. в программировании массив начинается с 0, первый элемент это индекс 0